# Today button in jQuery Datepicker doesn't work

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQueryUI Datepicker and show "Today" button.
But it doesn't work. It also doesn't work in demo: http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#buttonbar

I'w want to fill input with today when press this button.

Is it possible to get it working?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Their code is not really broken.  It just doesn't do what most people would expect it to do.  Which is to enter today's date into the input box. What it does do, is highlight for the user to see today's date on the calendar.  If they were off in another month or another year, the calendar pops back to today's view without deselecting the date the user already selected.

To make it more intuitive, you'll need to update the plugin code to suit your needs.  Let me know how it goes.

You'll need to get the uncompressed version of the jquery-ui javascript.  I'm looking at version 1.7.2 and the "_gotoToday" function is on line 6760.  Just add a call into that _gotoToday that fires off the _selectDate() function on line 6831.  :)  Happy Coding.

Comment: I don't like the solution of modifying the jQuery source code because it removes the ability to use a CDN. See my answer for how to modify the _gotoToday function without changing the plugin code file. (I would have kept this as a comment rather than an answer if  comments could include syntax highlighting)

Comment: I like GregL's suggestion better.

Comment: @WalterStabosz `comments can include syntax highlighting`

Comment: @AdrienBe thanks, I didn't know that in 2011 ... I'd fix it, but SO only allows comments to be edited for 5 minutes after they're posted :)

Comment: `<light-hearted-sarcasm>`"Their code is not really broken. It just doesn't do what most people would expect it to do" - in most people's opinion this is the definition of broken ;-)`</light-hearted-sarcasm>`

Answer (score 90):

I don't like the solution of modifying the jQuery source code because it removes the ability to use a CDN. Instead, you can reassign the _gotoToday function by including this code based on [@meesterjeeves answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337343/3993154) somewhere in your page's JavaScript scope file:

```
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
    var target = $(id);
    var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
    if (this._get(inst, 'gotoCurrent') && inst.currentDay) {
            inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay;
            inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth;
            inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear;
    }
    else {
            var date = new Date();
            inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
            inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
            inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
            // the below two lines are new
            this._setDateDatepicker(target, date);
            this._selectDate(id, this._getDateDatepicker(target));
    }
    this._notifyChange(inst);
    this._adjustDate(target);
}
```

The above code is essentially the same as the jQuery UI Datepicker from version 1.10.1 except for the two lines marked above. The whole mumble-jumbo with [`gotoCurrent`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-gotoCurrent) can actually be removed since that option does not make sense with our new meaning of "today".

Comment: I'm using it with jquery-1.6.2.min.js and /1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js, which aren't the latest versions. There may have been code changes in the new versions that break this hack.

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch. Have been trying all sorts of ways to make the Today button behave this way in IE but yours was the only one that worked.

Comment: This works for me in IE 7 and above, and in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have been looking solution for this problem.

Comment: @Sriram sorry, I wrote this answer months ago. I don't really remember how it works. I think it just overloads the Today button function. You'll have to reverse engineer it yourself.

Comment: I can confirm that this fix still works with jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.9.1. Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work for me (jquery 1.4.4, ui: 1.8) so I used:
`target.datepicker('setDate', date); target.datepicker('hide');` as the "added" code to the function.

Comment: This much shorter version worked for me (on v1.10.3): `$.datepicker._gotoToday = function (id) { $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur(); };`

Comment: @sinelaw - Thank you! This lovely tiny snippet worked like a charm :)

Comment: @sinelaw: That's nice and short, but comes with a caveat: it doesn't trigger the `change` event on the underlying `input` element.

Comment: @WalterStabosz I have a similar question to create a datepicker extension for the same CDN reason you gave. I am curious what your feedback might be. Could you take a look? [How to extend jQuery UI datepicker to modify Today button and add help icon] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066090/how-to-extend-jquery-ui-datepicker-to-modify-today-button-and-add-help-icon)

Comment: @ESS Sorry, I answered this question so long ago, I haven't looked at that code in many years. I'd say with all the code packaging and module  libraries we have now, the CDN issues probably isn't really the concern it was in 2011 (if it even was a concern). I'll leave you a comment on your question about further thought.

Answer (score 30):

I think the best way to handle this is to override the _goToToday method outside of the library itself.  This solved the issue for me:

```
var old_goToToday = $.datepicker._gotoToday
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
  old_goToToday.call(this,id)
  this._selectDate(id)
}
```

Simple and doesn't require you to hack up any events or change any underlying functionality

Comment: Little buggy (calendar won't re-appear until focus is removed) but otherwise works great.

Comment: Using 1.10.2, and works brilliantly. Added it in my shim configuration on init for requirejs: 
`shim: {        
        'datepicker': {
            deps: ['jquery','ui_core'],
            init: function ($, core) {
                var oldGoToToday = $.datepicker._gotoToday
                $.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
                    oldGoToToday.call(this, id);
                    this._selectDate(id);
                };
            }
        },
    }`

Comment: this worked for me, focus issue wasn't a problem since I use the option to only open on icon click, but if anyone else is working on focus and style issues, here are more answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139237/jquery-ui-datepicker-today-link

Comment: If you like this solution and want the input to also lose focus, just add `$(id).blur();` after `this._selectDate(id)`.

Comment: @itslittlejohn: Great tip; IE 11 and below need an additional tweak, unfortunately, otherwise the dialog will pop back up right away: append `$(id).datepicker('option', 'showOn', null); setTimeout(function () { $(id).datepicker('option', 'showOn', 'focus') })` to temporarily disable the date picker and then re-enable it after the `blur` event has finished processing.

Answer (score 13):

You should use the `todayBtn` option:

```
$("...").datepicker({
  todayBtn: "linked"
})
```

(instead of `todayBtn: true`).

> **todayBtn**
>
> Boolean, “linked”. Default: false
>
> If true or “linked”, displays a “Today” button at the bottom of the
>   datepicker to select the current date. If true, the “Today” button
>   will only move the current date into view; if “linked”, the current
>   date will also be selected.

For more details look at the following link:
http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#todaybtn

Comment: Noting that this is for the Bootstrap datepicker, not the jQuery UI datepicker as the questioner was looking for.

Comment: Even though this answer is to the wrong datepicker, I actually was looking at the bootstrap datepicker and found this answer, which fixed my problem! Thanks :D

Answer (score 9):

**Just add the following two lines of code to the _gotoToday function...**

```
/* Action for current link. */
_gotoToday: function(id) {
    var target = $(id);
    var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
    if (this._get(inst, 'gotoCurrent') && inst.currentDay) {
        inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay;
    inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth;
    inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear;
    }
    else {
        var date = new Date();
        inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
    }
    this._notifyChange(inst);
    this._adjustDate(target);

    /* ### CUSTOMIZATION: Actually select the current date, don't just show it ### */
    this._setDateDatepicker(target, new Date());
    this._selectDate(id, this._getDateDatepicker(target));
},
```

Answer (score 9):

Though I know this has already been accepted, here is my expanded solution based on [Samy Zine's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073410/today-button-in-jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work/7358962#7358962). This was using jQuery 1.6.3 and jQuery UI 1.8.16, and worked for me in Firefox 6.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-current').live('click', function() {
    // extract the unique ID assigned to the text input the datepicker is for
    // from the onclick attribute of the button
    var associatedInputSelector = $(this).attr('onclick').replace(/^.*'(#[^']+)'.*/gi, '$1');
    // set the date for that input to today's date
    var $associatedInput = $(associatedInputSelector).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    // (optional) close the datepicker once done
    $associatedInput.datepicker("hide");
});
```

You may wish to also `blur()` the `$associatedInput` and focus on the next input/select in your page, but that is not trivial to do generically, or is implementation-specific.

As an example, I did this on a page I was working on that used tables for layout (don't get me started, I know that is bad practice!):

```
$associatedInput.closest('tr').next('tr').find('input,select').first().focus();
```

Comment: Update: I did actually find issues with my solution here in IE (most versions). I ended up going with Walter Stabosz's approach instead, which did work in IE (as well as other browsers).

Answer (score 7):

I don't like the idea of adding extra code to jQuery source code. And I don't want to override `_gotoToday` method by copy-pasting its implementation somewhere in the javascript code and adding extra lines at the bottom.

So, I've tweaked it using this code:

```
(function(){
    var original_gotoToday = $.datepicker._gotoToday;

    $.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
        var target = $(id),
            inst = this._getInst(target[0]);

        original_gotoToday.call(this, id);
        this._selectDate(id, this._formatDate(inst, inst.selectedDay, inst.drawMonth, inst.drawYear));
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

I just got rid of it.

In some CSS file that's part of your page:

```
.ui-datepicker-current {
    visibility:hidden
}
```

Comment: No point to doing it this way since you could just pass in the option to hide the buttons. `showButtonPanel:false` - and this is the default value anyway.

Comment: Nope, as he only hid the Today button, not the Done button.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says what "today" button which title could be altered via

```
.datepicker('option', 'currentText', 'New Title')
```

only changes displayed month to current. This behaviour also could be configured

```
.datepicker('option', 'gotoCurrent', true);
```

After that pressing the button will change displayed month to selected date's one.

It seems submitting a date with this button is impossible by design.

Comment: Thank you very much, it saved me a lot of times.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code as well to fill current date in input box on click of Today button. Just put the below code in the `_gotoToday` function (at the end of the function) in `jquery.ui.datepicker.js`.

```
this._selectDate(id, this._formatDate(inst,
inst.selectedDay, inst.drawMonth, inst.drawYear));
```

Please note that I am using version 1.8.5 of jquery datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

I have added an option to the datepicker for that purpose: selectCurrent.

To do the same, you just have to add the following to the uncompressed js file:

1) Toward the end of function Datepicker(), add:

```
selectCurrent: false // True to select the date automatically when the current button is clicked
```

2) At the end of the _gotoToday function, add:

```
if (this._get(inst, 'selectCurrent'))
  this._selectDate(id, this._formatDate(inst, inst.selectedDay, inst.drawMonth, inst.drawYear));
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery UI Datepicker Today Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139237/jquery-ui-datepicker-today-link/5325284)

`$('button.ui-datepicker-current').live('click', function() {
    $.datepicker._curInst.input.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur();
});`

Comment: This correctly sets the current date, but it reopens the datepicker popup after setting it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
  var inst = this._getInst($(id)[0]);

  var date = new Date();
  this._selectDay(id, date.getMonth(), date.getFullYear(), inst.dpDiv.find('td.ui-datepicker-today'));
}

$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  changeMonth: true,
  maxDate: 'today',
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  showButtonPanel: true
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="id">
```

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker is being refactored to be at least 10 times more awesome. The new version will address this issue.

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137778/Datepicker

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to add this to your script :

```
$('.ui-datepicker-current').live('click', function() {
       $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", date);
});
```

( use .live function and not .click)

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack that worked for me that uses the Datepicker's beforeShow callback function as opposed to the live() approach.

```
     ,beforeShow: function(input, datepicker) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             datepicker.dpDiv.find('.ui-datepicker-current')
                .text('Select Today')
                .click(function() {
                     $(input)
                         .datepicker('setDate', new Date())
                         .datepicker('hide');
                });
         }, 1);
         return {};
     }
```

Comment: This on only works as long as you never change the month/Year on the calendar, if you change the month once, the Today button will work like it usually do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple hack

```
$(function() {
var _gotoToday = $.datepicker._gotoToday;
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(a){
var target = $(a);
var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
_gotoToday.call(this, a);
$.datepicker._selectDate(a, $.datepicker._formatDate(inst,inst.selectedDay, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedYear));
target.blur();
}

$( “#datepicker” ).datepicker({
showButtonPanel: true
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it a different way.

I find it irritating navigating to a date then having to remember to click on the day even if it is already selected (after clicking next/prev month).

Here I update the input field directly as we move around the months/years - which also fires when the Today button is clicked. I also need the change event to fire whenever the selection has changed.

```
$input.datepicker({
    ...
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst)
    {
        var date = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
        if (!isNaN(date))
        {
            input.value = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd M yy", date);
            $input.change();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for datetimepicker is to simple add icons properties in your code like this

```js
//And the script part like this
$('#fromFilterDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    showTodayButton :true,
    icons: {
      today:'fa fa-crosshairs'
    }
  });
```

```html
From Date
<input name = "fromFilterDate" autocomplete="off"  id="fromFilterDate" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who came lately like me for the similar issue with datetimepicker bootstrap4 version when using maxDate as Today the today button is not working. Here is a solution.
Try Following. It is because of the Time which comes with moment() object.

```
var today_string = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            $('#mydate').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                defaultDate: moment(),
                maxDate: moment(today_string+"T23:59:59"), //This is IMP
                icons: {
                    today: 'fa-solid fa-clock-rotate-left',
                },
                buttons: {
                    showToday: true
                },
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

(Please note, this isn't a question.  I am trying to be helpful by providing my solution since the other solutions did not work for me.)

I couldn't get the datepicker to stay hidden with any of the other answers.  The calendar would close and then re-open.  The below code worked for me to change the Today button to set the date to the current day and close the calendar.

jQuery UI - v1.11.4
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1
IE 11.0.28

I've included my defaults for completeness.

```js
    $.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
      var inst = this._getInst($(id)[0]);

      var date = new Date();
      this._selectDay(id, date.getMonth(), date.getFullYear(), inst.dpDiv.find('td.ui-datepicker-today'));
    }

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      changeMonth: true,
      maxDate: 'today',
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
```

Comment: The Answer area is meant for answers, not follow-up questions. Please consider posting this as a Question (linking to this one within it), or as a comment on the question or one of the existing answers.