# jQuery DatePicker: When clicking on Today and then Done, today's date is not preserved

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When using datepicker, when I click on the "Today" button then today's date is shown in datepicker. However, when I click on the "Done" button then today's date is not displayed in the field. Currently, I have to actually click on the date (i.e., Today -> select date). I would prefer clicking Today -> Done.

How can I click on a date field, click on the "Today" button and then click on the "Done" button and to have today's date reflected in the date field?

**Update:**

Below is what I am experimenting with. Pardon the mess - I am new to jQuery / javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            yearRange: 2000:c+1,
            showButtonPanel: true,                       
            @*
               beforeShow: function (input, instance) {
                $(input).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
            }
            *@
        });

        $('.datePicker').click(function () {
            $('button.ui-datepicker-current').removeClass('ui-priority-secondary').addClass('ui-priority-primary');
        });            

        $(document).on('click', "button.ui-datepicker-current", function () {
            $(".datePicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date())
        });

        @* Set focus to the next datepicker. This allows the user to re-select the same date field.
           Otherwise, a user must click another date field in order to be able to re-select the date field.
        *@
        $("body").delegate("button[data-handler=today]", "click", function () {
            $("#Date").datepicker("setDate", new Date()).datepicker("hide");
            $("#RDate").focus();
        });

        @* This does not work, but provided for ideas.
        $(".datepicker").each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', $(this).val());
        });
        *@
    });
```

Comment: That is not the behavior of the button, but [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139237/jquery-ui-datepicker-today-link) suggest a possible solution

Comment: I saw that and was able to use the solution for changing the formatting of the "Today" button. But, I was unable to get the functionality of "Today" -> "Done" to work. Are you able to do it and provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it with something very similar to the example given by Stephen in the comments, it just needed tweaking slightly to get the event handler to work properly, and to stop it immediately closing the datepicker after "Today" was clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datePicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    yearRange: "2000:c+1",
    showButtonPanel: true
  });

  $(document).on('click', "button.ui-datepicker-current", function() {
    $(".datePicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date())
  });
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ornc4gv/12/

**Edit**

If you have multiple datepickers on the page with the same "datepicker" CSS class, the click event above will change the date on all of them.

To prevent this, alter the click event handler as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', "button.ui-datepicker-current", function() {
  $.datepicker._curInst.input.datepicker('setDate', new Date())   
});
```

Credit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5325284/5947043 for the correct method to use.

Comment: Excellent! That is an elegant solution. Thank you very much. I tip my hat to you, sir.

Comment: Actually, that does not work because it affects all date fields on the page. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @JWeezy made an edit to suggest what you need to do in that situation.

Comment: Will do - I will have to check this tonight. Thanks again for your help. I know this may be a shameless plug, but any chance this question is worth an upvote? Posts with useful answers should not suffer negative down votes.

Comment: That worked. I posted another question with respect to how the "Today" button is rendered. If you can get it to work then happy to mark it answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164670/jquery-datepicker-prevent-the-today-button-from-being-grayed-out