# Adding event listener on 'Today' button in jquery-ui datapicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the datepicker form jQuery-ui-1.8.16.

I have the following code:

```
Site.Calendar = function() {

    // Set default setting for all calendars
    jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn : 'both',
        buttonImageOnly : true,
        buttonText: '',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        showOtherMonths : true,
        selectOtherMonths : true,
        showButtonPanel : true,
        dateFormat : "D, d M, yy",
        showAnim : "slideDown",
        onSelect: Site.Calendar.customiseTodayButton
    });
};

Site.Calendar.customiseTodayButton = function(dateText, inst) {
    console.log("hello");
};
```

My customiseTodayButton function is only getting triggered when I select an actual date and NOT on the Today button.

Is there any way to override how the today button work's in the jQuery datepicker?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the following posted here:
[Today button in jQuery Datepicker doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073410/today-button-in-jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work)

```
jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
        var target = jQuery(id);
        var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
        if (this._get(inst, 'gotoCurrent') && inst.currentDay) {
                inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay;
                inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth;
                inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear;
        }
        else {
                var date = new Date();
                inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
                inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
                inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
                this._setDateDatepicker(target, date);
                this._selectDate(id, this._getDateDatepicker(target));
        }
        this._notifyChange(inst);
        this._adjustDate(target);
    }
```

It simply rewrites the goToToday method and adds two new lines:

```
this._setDateDatepicker(target, date);
this._selectDate(id, this._getDateDatepicker(target));
```

Maybe there is a cleaner way to fix this with your original answer Mark?

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a standard event for when the today button is clicked.  However, taking a look at the jquery.ui.datepicker.js code, it appears that it calls `$.datepicker._gotoToday`.  I'll assume by `customizeTodayButton` you're attempting to change the behavior of what it does currently (not the looks, the looks would be done with styling).  To change the existing behavior, it's good to know what it does now.  So, that in mind, this is the current code of the function used:

```
/* Action for current link. */
_gotoToday: function(id) {
    var target = $(id);
    var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
    if (this._get(inst, 'gotoCurrent') && inst.currentDay) {
        inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay;
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth;
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear;
    }
    else {
        var date = new Date();
        inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
    }
    this._notifyChange(inst);
    this._adjustDate(target);
},
```

To override this function with your own functionality, you'll want to do update your code to something like this:

```
Site.Calendar = function() {
    //override the existing _goToToday functionality
    $.datepicker._gotoTodayOriginal = $.datepicker._gotoToday;
    $.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
        // now, call the original handler
        $.datepicker._gotoTodayOriginal.apply(this, [id]);
        // invoke selectDate to select the current date and close datepicker.
        $.datepicker._selectDate.apply(this, [id]);
    };

    // Set default setting for all calendars
    jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: '',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: "D, d M, yy",
        showAnim: "slideDown"
    });
};
```

Also, here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/9Ru72/) of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I want to make the Today button behave like the date buttons i.e. selecting the Today button updates the input field to todays date and closes the calendar. I should be able to figure it out based on your response :)

Comment: So this code won't work right, I forgot that the datepicker doesn't actually use the ui widget class like the rest of the ui components.  Updating answer now, and adding exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Mark. Unfortunately it is not working in IE :( The Calendar seems to be closing and reopening very quickly when selecting the Today button. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the a solution that works across all main browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox)...see my new post in this thread

Answer (score 3):

I realized the overriding of the <kbd>today</kbd> button in this way:

```
jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dateRef = jQuery("<td><a>" + today.getDate() + "</a></td>");
    this._selectDay(id, today.getMonth(), today.getFullYear(), dateRef);
};
```

This is quite simple and does the "select date and close datepicker" functionality that I would.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to say today.getDay() inside td