# DatePicker With Today and DateFormat

Tags: html, jquery-ui, input, datepicker, buttonclick

I have been trying to create a jQuery UI function for the datepicker, and after reading all the forums and snippets out there, I realize that a vast majority of answers have been deprecated and/or removed from jQuery 1.9.1.

Very Simply, I need to have the jquery datepicker

Display the datepicker with the options of buttons as well as be able to click on today which will automatically enter the date into my input field.  For the life of me I can't figure this out and wanted to toss it to someone more knowledgeable in jQuery/ jQuery-UI.

#### Had Tried Something Like:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker(("setDate", new Date()){
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'm-d-yy'
    });
  });
```

#### And of course the html

```
  <input name="date" id="date" />
```

The inputed value should be in standard USA date format:   i.e.  5/1/2013  or 12/31/2099.

As of now, the code doesn't select the current date, and obviously clicking today will only select today's date.  I need it to automatically populate the input field.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that most of us (and so did I) missunderstand the functionality of the "today" button.
In fact it is just a button to **highlight** the current date and not to select it.

If you do want a behaviour where the user clicks on today and the datepicker selects the current date I'd recommend you to see a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8MACJ/) I created.

As this is not my work and I just did some research (working with datepicker at the moment too) I kindly refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7613795/2240272) solution which works perfect with jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2.

This is the code which solves your issue

```
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function (id) {
    var target = $(id);
    var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
    if (this._get(inst, 'gotoCurrent') && inst.currentDay) {
        inst.selectedDay = inst.currentDay;
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = inst.currentMonth;
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = inst.currentYear;
    } else {
        var date = new Date();
        inst.selectedDay = date.getDate();
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = date.getMonth();
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = date.getFullYear();
        // the below two lines are new
        this._setDateDatepicker(target, date);
        this._selectDate(id, this._getDateDatepicker(target));
    }
    this._notifyChange(inst);
    this._adjustDate(target);
}
```

I hope this may help you :)

**EDIT**

To prepopulate your input field with the current date you need to use the [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method.
Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8MACJ/2/)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Comment: your answer has been instrumental in the final solution to my problem... thank you so much!!  however the final solution was both a combination of your answer and thanos's

Comment: Oh well seems like I skipped a bit of your question in my solution. What a pitty prepopulating the input would be easy peasy ^^

Comment: I was just about to edit my post when I saw your own answer. Already created the fiddle...just posted the edit. Hope the dateformat is correct because you mentioned you want it in standard US format.

Comment: format for standard us is m-d-yy.... well, thats slightly incorrect...mm-dd-yy and m-d-yy is both USA format, just one has leading 0's and one is cleaner...i prefer m-d-yy

Comment: Haha ok I was confused because you wrote "standard USA date format: i.e. 5/1/2013" with / as delimiter. Edited the fiddle another time, should now be m-d-yy ;) Your're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I've created an **[EXAMPLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rh7U6/1/)** for you that think would cover what you ask.

EDIT: Updated the **[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/rh7U6/12/)** and removed the initial date selection. Now it starts without any selected date.

HTML

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

JS (don't forget yo include jQuery UI 1.9.2 and jQuery )

```
var $datepicker = $("#datepicker");
$datepicker.datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'm-d-yy'
    });
$datepicker.datepicker('setDate');
```

Comment: it does help, however, if i was to switch the date, then reclick the calendar.... the today button still does not have any functionality.  I like that onLoad, the date is prepopulated though...  any ideas?