# Turn on Today button on date picker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using a date picker from this source http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar , I am trying to let "Today" button on the button bar to be active, can any one help me please.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true, closeText: 'Clear',
             gotoCurrent : true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1900, 2300',
            dateFormat: _DateFormatDatePicker,             
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
                var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the getDate method
                document.getElementById('<%=hdnTempDate.ClientID%>').value = dateText;
            }
```

Comment: That may help you to answer me
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-currentText

Comment: wat do you mean by getting it "active"?

Comment: Not simple as it appears, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073410/today-button-in-jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    buttonImage: buttonCalendar,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: ""
});
```

and call this js code in the pages where you have the calendar.

```
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) { 
    $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur(); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the `$.datepicker._gotoToday = function(id) { 
    $(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur(); 
};`

Comment: A bit more correct is `$(id).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker('hide').blur().change();`

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Enable the Buttons panel by: `showButtonPanel: true`. Then place the following code after your datepicker JS code:

```
var _gotoToday = jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday;
jQuery.datepicker._gotoToday = function(a){
    var target = jQuery(a);
    var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
    _gotoToday.call(this, a);
    jQuery.datepicker._selectDate(a, jQuery.datepicker._formatDate(inst,inst.selectedDay, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedYear));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code instead.

```
todayBtn: "linked",
```

And a bonus code that clear the input field

```
clearBtn: true,
```

Final code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  showButtonPanel: true,
  closeText: 'Clear',
  todayBtn: "linked",
  clearBtn: true,
  gotoCurrent : true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '1900, 2300',
  dateFormat: _DateFormatDatePicker,             
  onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
    var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the getDate method
    document.getElementById('<%=hdnTempDate.ClientID%>').value = dateText;
  }
```