# jQuery Datepicker today button does not put today's date in the input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need your help,

I just added the buttonpane to my Date Picker, however it seems that when I click on the 'Today' button, what should happen is that it should select the present date and also put its value into the input box.

What am I doing wrong?

```
            $("#date1").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: 'images/cal.png',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onSelect: function() {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('invalid') == true) { $(this).removeClass('invalid') }
                    $(this).change();
                }

            });//end of datepicker
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="date1">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Today button in jQuery Datepicker doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073410/today-button-in-jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work)

Comment: see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073410/today-button-in-jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not designed to do that, it's only designed to take the calendar view back to today if you navigate to another month.

See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7613795/4704856) about how to modify the functionality.