# How to add a placeholder to jqGrid text field in the header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

[image]

My jqgrid contains multiple fields and I want to filter the grid. For example, assume my grid contains 'name' field and I want to filter the grid's data with name="aron". Now, I would like to instruct the user that saying you should enter only names in this field to filter the grid.

I am very new to jqGrid and need someone's help to move forward. I want to add a placeholder to the header row text fields on grids, as I can give some instruction to the user to enter the data for filtering. I want to make it generic, whenever I add a text field to my grid a generic placeholder(input hint) should be added to it. I am not sure how my `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` works and where to make the changes to achieve my requirement.

Can anyone please help me in this matter..??

Thanks in advance,
Santosh Manne.

```
 model.dataType = dataType;
    if (dataType == 'datetime' || dataType == 'date') {
        if (!model.formatter){
    model.formatter = 'date';
    }
    formatColumns += '<Column><ColName>'+model.xmlmap+'</ColName><ColType>'+dataType+'</ColType></Column>';

        if (!model.formatoptions) {
            model.formatoptions = {
              srcformat: 'SortableDateTime',
              newformat: (dataType == 'date')?'Y-m-d':'Y-m-d H:i:s',
              defaultValue: null
            };
        }
        else {
            if (!model.formatoptions.srcformat)
                model.formatoptions.srcformat = 'SortableDateTime';
            if (!model.formatoptions.newformat)
                model.formatoptions.newformat = (dataType == 'date')?'Y-m-d':'Y-m-d H:i:s';
        }
        if (dataType == 'date') {
            model.searchoptions.dataInit = function(el) {
                $(el).datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', pickDate:true, pickTime:false});
            };
        }
        else {
            model.searchoptions.dataInit = function(el) {
                $(el).datetimepicker({format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', useSeconds:true, sideBySide:false});
            };
        }
        model.width = 210;
    }
```

moreover my jqgrid implementation would be like below.

`<DataGrid>
        <Columns>
           <Column name="date" mapping="createdDate".../>
        </Columns>
    </DataGrid>`

Comment: You know, there is a website? http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/ ... And it has demos with code samples. At least show us you've tried something.

Comment: We have an overridden file named DataGrid.js for jquery.jqGrid.min.js, which gives support for xml tags. So, all my jqgrid code would be in xml format and internally it is converted to script by DataGrid.hs. Please find my code for a datagrid below. @MokonaModoki

Comment: @MokonaModoki <DataGrid> <Columns> <Column name="test" map="myMappingField" ../>... </Columns> </DataGrid>

Comment: If this xml extension is built internally in your team, why would anyone out there know how to use it?

Comment: @santoshM: 1) You should post all information about the question *in the text of the question (click "edit" under the question and modify the text) 2) You sould post more details about what you do and what you need to implement. The XML fragment about `DataGrid` have no information about your question. Which "generic placeholder(input hint)" you need at add and where? Sorry, but I still have no idea what you need to implement. Look [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for the first information about jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg: I have edited my question. Can you please check it and suggest.

Comment: @santoshM: Do you tried jqGrid already? Do you filled the data in the grid? **Where is your current code and the test data?** If you need to add the filter in the grid then you need just call `filterToolbar` after the grid is created. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm) for example, it contains many other options which you don't need now, but the filter toolbar will be created in the demo by call `.jqGrid("filterToolbar")`

Comment: @Oleg: Yeah Oleg, in the example demo I can see a grid. My datagrid exactly matches the datagrid in the demo. The issue I am facing here is, date field in my datagrid is not working fine if I give the date like 12-1-2016. So, I just want to give the hint to user that the date field should be entered with mm/dd/yyyy format. For this reason, I need to insert an input hint (placeholder) to that field.

Comment: @santoshM: Why you write always about **datagrid**? Do you use datagrid or jqGrid? You wrote about "date field in my datagrid". **You posted no code and no pictures.** You just *describe* smoothing, but I suppose that you use *wrong terminology*. Thus I have still no idea whether we speak about the same things or not.

Comment: @Oleg: Hi Oleg, I have added a screenshot to the question. Here, when a date is selected from the datepicker, it gives me the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. Instead I am copying and pasting the date with format mm-dd-yy as seen in the screenshot. When I hit the enter key, it accepts the format but ends with no result even though the matching data is present in the db. In this scenario, I want to put an user input hint saying, only mm/dd/yyyy format is allowed.

Comment: @santoshM: The picture don't display the format of dates in the column. Is the text in the column in the mm/dd/yyyy format? Why the user should use another wrong date format? If the user use datepicker then the inserted date will be correct. Of cause I suppose that you use *correct options of datepicker and correct properties of the column in `colModel`*. You don't posted any JavaScript code, so I don't understand where you made an error. Moreover the text of your question contains still "datagrid" instead of "jqGrid". It's like usage iOS and to mean Android or Linux instead of Windows.

Comment: @Oleg: Yeah Oleg, I have made the changes in question (i.e. datagrid to grid/jqgrid). Coming to the screenshot, in the date column's text field I have pasted the date as 12-1-15. I want to show a placeholder there, with the supported format (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy). I need the changes to my text field (i.e. <input type="text" name="gs_date".../>) and the changes should be like (<input type="text" name="gs_date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy".../>.

Comment: @santoshM: I can only repeat: **you should include JavaScript code which you use**. All "input" element will be created dynamically based on your JavaScript code (the definition of the column `date` in your case and the options of `datepicker`).

Comment: @santoshM: Look at the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0v6vkx75/1/. Is it what you want to implement?

Comment: @Oleg: Yeah Oleg, I can add the JavaScript code. To add any jqgrid to my project, I write all the code in xml based language. These are converted into JavaScript by DataGrid.js, which is an overriden file of jquery.jqGrid.min.js file. For datetime picker depends on jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js. I am pasting some code snippet on screen and I am very new to this. I am not sure whether it helps you or not.

Comment: @santoshM: Sorry, but the goal of stackpoverflow to share the descriptions of *common problems* and the corresponding solution. Nobody have an interest about internal format of data which you use to describe the grid and  how you generate the options of jqGrid. You should just post **the input parameters** of jqGrid. Only in the case the question can have any value for other. Moreover I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0v6vkx75/1/ (see my previous comment), which should be close to what you want to implement. You posted no comments about it.

Comment: @santoshM: You wrote before that you want to display the date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, but the last code seems to use ISO date format. Why? What you really need?

Comment: @Oleg, hi Oleg! I have got the solution for the above question. Anyhow Thanks for you help and the response on time.

Comment: @santoshM: Sorry, but if you want just add `placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm'` attribute to searching field then you can better do this inside of `dataInit` callback of `searchoptions`. More better and simple way is the usage of `attr` like `attr: { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" }`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0v6vkx75/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to add `placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm'` attribute to `<input>` element of the searching toolbar then you can use

```js
searchoptions: {
    attr: { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" }
}
```

see the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0v6vkx75/3/

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have an extension to the above question, just would like to get the value of this placeholder from another .js file. Can I get the value of this placeholder attribute using colModel object? @Oleg

Comment: @santoshM: I'm not sure want you mean. The `searchoptions.attr.placeholder` is already the part of `colModel`. Do you want to hold multiple parameters of `colModel` synchronous (the same)? It could be that the usage of `template` in the columns could be the feature which you could use. I'm not sure, whether you knows column templates and whether you use the feature. I implemented in free jqGrid the possibility to define `template` as function, which seems be what you need. It would be better if you post separate question where you describe exactly your problem and what you need to implement.

Comment: Thanks for sharing complete code on jsFiddle. However, the `Today` button on datepicker isn't working on date column filter.

Comment: @Yayati: If I correctly understand your question then it's pure question about jQuery UI datepicker independent on jqGrid. Look at [the demo](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#buttonbar) from the official jQuery UI site. See [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073410/today-button-in-jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work/7613795#comment28597767_7613795). Look at [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0v6vkx75/5/) which uses the code. It's probably not final solution, but the Today button works now.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to get the column names in jqgrid "loadcomplete",

add this code to it:

$("gs_YourColumnNamePropertyValue").attr("placeholder","YourText");

add as many columns you want.

Comment: You should post such remarks as the comment to the question and not as the answer on the question.

Comment: I know @Oleg. I have added a note to it, thats why. I cant comment until I get 50 reputation.

Comment: Hi Oleg & Rustin, I have edited my question and commented the code snippet to it. Can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.  @Oleg

Comment: I do understand how you implement jqgrid. I have implemented in the same way. But to your question, it has no relation, in what scenario and how do you add textboxes?

Comment: @RustinCohle: I have edited my question, can you please look into it. I just want to add the place holder to a field's header, which suggests the user to enter only specified data to filter the grid.

Comment: @santoshM So you mean the Search toolbar, the textboxes on top of each column to filter the columns?

Comment: @RustinCohle Yeah, exactly. I just want to add a input hint to the header text boxes. User can be guided what kind of data he can enter to filter the grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103801/discussion-between-rustin-cohle-and-santoshm).

Comment: @RustinCohle Hi Rustin, I have got the solution for the above question and posted the answer. Thanks for your kind help and time. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am sending datetime as my dataType from xyz.jsp. The same is checked in jquery.jqGrid.min.js and added the placeholder to it.

```
if(k.dataType == 'datetime')
a("td:eq(1)", s).append("<input type='text' placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm' style='width:100%;padding:0px;' name='" + (k.index || k.name) + "' id='gs_" + k.name + "' value='" + v + "'/>");
else
a("td:eq(1)", s).append("<input type='text' style='width:100%;padding:0px;' name='" + (k.index || k.name) + "' id='gs_" + k.name + "' value='" + v + "'/>");
```